# What is the difference between Set,Map,WeakSet,WeakMap in ES6?

Tags: ecmascript-6

I confused between Set, Map, WeakSet and WeakMap because from each one of this we can add and delete items from list and also we can show data from the list by using either one.

What should I use and When? Please assist me.

Comment: Do you want to know the difference between a set and a map or do you want to know what weak means in this context?

Comment: @zeroflagL WeakSet(),WeakMap() are two another method of ES6, I want to know the difference between them

Comment: Isn't the documentation, especially the point "Why Weak-Map" clear enough? https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakMap